# Find a two variable function which is one to one but not onto

Tags: functions

Can any of you suggest me a two variable function which is one to one but not onto?
At $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ range!

Comment: Does the function have to be between two specific sets?

Comment: What do you mean sets? Just a two variable function in NxN that will be one to one but no onto

Comment: What do you mean, what do you mean sets? Is $\Bbb N$ not a set? (Also: sorry @anakh, I wouldn't have made the edit if I had seen yours in queue :/ )

Comment: I dont speak good english... now i understand what you meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any pair $(a,b)$ of natural numbers, let $f(a,b)=2^a(2b+1)$. If we want it to be very not onto, use $f(a,b)=8^a(8b+1)$.

Comment: You are welcome. I am confident that you can verify that the examples do the job.

Comment: Yes i can... also can you suggest any onto but one to one 2 variable NxN?

Comment: That's much easier, let $f(x,y)=x$.

Comment: Cant get that one.. Why it is not one to one?

Comment: Maybe you are having trouble because it is so simple. Obviously onto. Not one to one, since $f(17,1)=f(17,2)=f(17,999)=17$.  If you want an example that "mentions" both $x$ and $y$ we can use $x+y-1$.

Comment: is f(x,y) = 2x-y an onto but one to one? I think yes am i right?

Comment: You mean onto but not one to one? Not  a good example, because for example if $x=3$ and $y=99$, then $f(x,y)$ is negative. But the $x+y-1$ that I mentioned above does not have that problem. Still, I like $f(x,y)=x$ better!